# Selenium Java Selecting option on dynamic dropdown element not visible

Tags: java, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm not expert at selenium but I'm trying to do something that seems so easy. I've already searched around here and none of the options work, short of some JavaScript executors that I don't know how to use at all really, but even then, seem kind of hacky (unless that's the way you're supposed to write selenium?)

First problem is I can't select by id, since it is always different, but for debugging purposes I've been using the ugly xpath to at least click on the drop down:

```
xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/span/div").click()
```

But now, when I do a

```
xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/span/select").select("boolean");
```

Where `.select` is just a wrapper that does a:

```
Select.selectByValue();
```

I get an element not visible even though it is! Any help would be appreciated as it's driving me nuts. I'll keep trying out the suggestions other people posted on other questions, but so far nada.

Comment: is it possible to post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("#input439_chzn")).click();
driver.findELements(By.cssSelector(#input439_chzn > div > ul > li:nth-of-type(2)));
```

That should select the second item on you drop down.

if you want a random item get the size of the drop down and do a random between 1 and the size.